# Combine two `align` in one

Tags: align

Consider the minimal code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]%
\begin{align*}
m_{1}(x) &=x(x-1)=x^{2}-x, & m_{2}(x)&=x^{2}(x-1)=x^{3}-x^{2},
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
m_{3}(x) &=x(x-1)^{2}=x^{3}-2x^{2}+x.
\end{align*}%
\lipsum*[3]
\end{document}
```

producing

[image]

What is the best way to have the same result but with a smaller vertical space between the two lines, but using only one environment?

Of course I can try to use `\vspace{negative space}` between those two `align*` but I'm afraid it could be dangerous.

Comment: given that the alignment points are different I suspect a negative vspace between the two is the only way. Of course answers may vary in how far they go to  hide the negative space or the two separate alignments from the document markup

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, maybe some negative vertical space but with those options to expand or contract? I don't want to have a so hard vertical space. It could be small if necessary to better format my page.

Comment: I see what you're asking for - but why? Might your equations be easier to read if they were in three lines with the first equal signs aligned? Then the reader could easily compare the expressions for the functions m_1.

Comment: @Sigur I'd use the same spaces ams uses (which is `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplaysip` I think, same as a primitive `$$` display)

Comment: @EthanBolker, I need to save space. When possible I insert everything in one line, but sometimes I need one line more.

Answer (score 7):

in your example, nothing is actually aligned, in spite of the use of `&`.  alignment
implies that more than one line is involved.

i suggest using `gather*` instead:

```
\begin{gather*}
m_{1}(x) =x(x-1)=x^{2}-x, \qquad m_{2}(x)=x^{2}(x-1)=x^{3}-x^{2},\\
m_{3}(x) =x(x-1)^{2}=x^{3}-2x^{2}+x.
\end{gather*}
```

[image: output of example code]

if you want to add a bit more space between the two lines, you can always put an
optional dimension right after the double backslash (don't leave a typed space
before the opening bracket!):

```
... \\[2pt]
```

suggestion: read the `amsmath` users guide (`texdoc amsmath`) to see what options
exist for formatting multi-line displays.  there are quite a few, with quite varied
possibilities.

Comment: Awww, you beat me to this very answer by a few seconds!

Comment: @Mico -- which answer -- the `gather*` or "read the documentation"?

Comment: @barbarabeeton, thanks. I have some blocks with more than 3 expressions. But if they fit only in one line, I use one. If necessary, I split the line in two, like my example. I was supposing that the space between the items on the same line could be evenly spaced. This is not the case if I use `\quad` isn't?

Comment: @Sigur -- i think you're using the `align` approach to get the spacing between actual equations done automatically (i.e., that separation will be larger than the space around an `=`).  i have an appointment now, but i'll try to come back to this later.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - the `gather*` part...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't really see the `align*` environment as doing anything other than providing horizontal space between the top two expressions.  If that is the case, then a simple stack can accomplish your goal or reducing the vertical gap.  Note that the gap itself is specified as an optional stacking argument.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]%
\begin{equation*}
\stackunder[10pt]{m_{1}(x) =x(x-1)=x^{2}-x,\quad\qquad m_{2}(x)=x^{2}(x-1)=x^{3}-x^{2},}%
  {m_{3}(x) =x(x-1)^{2}=x^{3}-2x^{2}+x.}
\end{equation*}
\lipsum*[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]